# EZAudio - How to change waveform size same according to size of the view using EZAudioPlotGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ezaudio

I am using the `EZAudio` library for `iOS` to handle the playback of an audio file and generate its waveform.

I'd like to create the view with the entire waveform using the `EZAudioPlotGL` view which is a subclass of `UIView`.

Can anyone help me to increase the size of the wave as the view size using `EZAudioPlotGL`.

Answer (score 2):

Just increase the gain value like below.

```
objectOfEZAudioPlotGL.gain = 2.0f; //default gain value is 1.0f
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the plot was added to your view... Something like this:

```
plot.setFrameSize( self.bounds.size )
```